# Python 3(.5.2) Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, messagebox

I need help. I was developing an interface with tkinter. at one point, when I insert a button in the window, it does not work as it should ... in fact, does not work. I give me this error when i press the button:

```
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/Edoardo/Desktop/Progetti/Programming Projects/Python Projects/Encoder 1.0 alpha.py", line 277, in <lambda>
encode = Button(text="ENCODE", command=lambda: encode())
TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable
```

This is the code (some parts are missing cause, before write the entire program, i want make sure that it works):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

# encode = {char : code}
utf8int = {
    "!": "\\33",
    "\"": "\\34",
    "#": "\\35",
    "$": "\\36",
    "%": "\\37",
    "&": "\\38",
    "'": "\\39",
    "(": "\\40",
    ")": "\\41",
    "*": "\\42",
    "+": "\\43",
    ",": "\\44",
    "-": "\\45",
    ".": "\\46",
    "/": "\\47",
    "0": "\\48",
    "1": "\\49",
    "2": "\\50",
    "3": "\\51",
    "4": "\\52",
    "5": "\\53",
    "6": "\\54",
    "7": "\\55",
    "8": "\\56",
    "9": "\\57",
    ":": "\\58",
    ";": "\\59",
    "<": "\\60",
    "=": "\\61",
    ">": "\\62",
    "?": "\\63",
    "@": "\\64",
    "A": "\\65",
    "B": "\\66",
    "C": "\\67",
    "D": "\\68",
    "E": "\\69",
    "F": "\\70",
    "G": "\\71",
    "H": "\\72",
    "I": "\\73",
    "J": "\\74",
    "K": "\\75",
    "L": "\\76",
    "M": "\\77",
    "N": "\\78",
    "O": "\\79",
    "P": "\\80",
    "Q": "\\81",
    "R": "\\82",
    "S": "\\83",
    "T": "\\84",
    "U": "\\85",
    "V": "\\86",
    "W": "\\87",
    "X": "\\88",
    "Y": "\\89",
    "Z": "\\90",
    "[": "\\91",
    "\\": "\\92",
    "]": "\\93",
    "^": "\\94",
    "_": "\\95",
    "`": "\\96",
    "a": "\\97",
    "b": "\\98",
    "c": "\\99",
    "d": "\\100",
    "e": "\\101",
    "f": "\\102",
    "g": "\\103",
    "h": "\\104",
    "i": "\\105",
    "j": "\\106",
    "k": "\\107",
    "l": "\\108",
    "m": "\\109",
    "n": "\\110",
    "o": "\\111",
    "p": "\\112",
    "q": "\\113",
    "r": "\\114",
    "s": "\\115",
    "t": "\\116",
    "u": "\\117",
    "v": "\\118",
    "w": "\\119",
    "x": "\\120",
    "y": "\\121",
    "z": "\\122",
    "{": "\\123",
    "|": "\\124",
    "}": "\\125",
    "~": "\\126",
    "€": "\\128",
    "‚": "\\130",
    "ƒ": "\\131",
    "„": "\\132",
    "…": "\\133",
    "†": "\\134",
    "‡": "\\135",
    "ˆ": "\\136",
    "‰": "\\137",
    "Š": "\\138",
    "‹": "\\139",
    "Œ": "\\140",
    "Ž": "\\142",
    "‘": "\\145",
    "’": "\\146",
    "“": "\\147",
    "”": "\\148",
    "•": "\\149",
    "–": "\\150",
    "—": "\\151",
    "˜": "\\152",
    "™": "\\153",
    "š": "\\154",
    "›": "\\155",
    "œ": "\\156",
    "ž": "\\158",
    "Ÿ": "\\159",
    "¡": "\\161",
    "¢": "\\162",
    "£": "\\163",
    "¤": "\\164",
    "¥": "\\165",
    "¦": "\\166",
    "§": "\\167",
    "¨": "\\168",
    "©": "\\169",
    "ª": "\\170",
    "«": "\\171",
    "¬": "\\172",
    "®": "\\174",
    "¯": "\\175",
    "°": "\\176",
    "±": "\\177",
    "²": "\\178",
    "³": "\\179",
    "´": "\\180",
    "µ": "\\181",
    "¶": "\\182",
    "·": "\\183",
    "¸": "\\184",
    "¹": "\\185",
    "º": "\\186",
    "»": "\\187",
    "¼": "\\188",
    "½": "\\189",
    "¾": "\\190",
    "¿": "\\191",
    "À": "\\192",
    "Á": "\\193",
    "Â": "\\194",
    "Ã": "\\195",
    "Ä": "\\196",
    "Å": "\\197",
    "Æ": "\\198",
    "Ç": "\\199",
    "È": "\\200",
    "É": "\\201",
    "Ê": "\\202",
    "Ë": "\\203",
    "Ì": "\\204",
    "Í": "\\205",
    "Î": "\\206",
    "Ï": "\\207",
    "Ð": "\\208",
    "Ñ": "\\209",
    "Ò": "\\210",
    "Ó": "\\211",
    "Ô": "\\212",
    "Õ": "\\213",
    "Ö": "\\214",
    "×": "\\215",
    "Ø": "\\216",
    "Ù": "\\217",
    "Ú": "\\218",
    "Û": "\\219",
    "Ü": "\\220",
    "Ý": "\\221",
    "Þ": "\\222",
    "ß": "\\223",
    "à": "\\224",
    "á": "\\225",
    "â": "\\226",
    "ã": "\\227",
    "ä": "\\228",
    "å": "\\229",
    "æ": "\\230",
    "ç": "\\231",
    "è": "\\232",
    "é": "\\233",
    "ê": "\\234",
    "ë": "\\235",
    "ì": "\\236",
    "í": "\\237",
    "î": "\\238",
    "ï": "\\239",
    "ð": "\\240",
    "ñ": "\\241",
    "ò": "\\242",
    "ó": "\\243",
    "ô": "\\244",
    "õ": "\\245",
    "ö": "\\246",
    "÷": "\\247",
    "ø": "\\248",
    "ù": "\\249",
    "ú": "\\250",
    "û": "\\251",
    "ü": "\\252",
    "ý": "\\253",
    "þ": "\\254",
    "ÿ": "\\255",
    "Ā": "\\256",
    "ā": "\\257",
    "Ă": "\\258",
    "ă": "\\259",
    "Ą": "\\260",
    "ą": "\\261",
    "Ć": "\\262",
    "ć": "\\263",
    "Ĉ": "\\264",
    "ĉ": "\\265",
    "Ċ": "\\266",
    "ċ": "\\267",
    "Č": "\\268",
    "č": "\\269",
    "Ď": "\\270",
    "ď": "\\271",
    "Đ": "\\272",
    "đ": "\\273"
}

utf8hex = {

}

Ascii = {

}

binary = {

}

root = Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Encoder 1.0 (Alpha)")

v = IntVar()

infoLabel = Label(text="This is an encoder, please choose the encode type and enter a message ")
infoLabel.grid(column=1, columnspan=3, row=1)

RB_UTF8_int = Radiobutton(text="UTF-8 (int)", variable=v, value="utf-8 int")
RB_UTF8_int.grid(column=1, row=2)

RB_UTF8_hex = Radiobutton(text="UTF-8 (hex)", variable=v, value="utf-8 hex")
RB_UTF8_hex.grid(column=2, row=2)

RB_Ascii = Radiobutton(text="Ascii", variable=v, value="Ascii")
RB_Ascii.grid(column=1, row=3)

RB_UTF16 = Radiobutton(text="Binary", variable=v, value="binary")
RB_UTF16.grid(column=2, row=3)

message = Entry()
message.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=4)

encode = Button(text="ENCODE", command=lambda: encode())
encode.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=5)

root.mainloop()


def encode():
    errors = 0
    decoded_message = []
    encoded_message = []
    for i in message.get():
        decoded_message.append(i)
    if message.get() != "":
        if v == "utf-8 int":
            for i in decoded_message:
                for char, code in utf8int:
                    if char == i:
                        encoded_message.append(code)
                    else:
                        encoded_message.append("(error)")
                        errors += 1
                        pass
            decoded_message1 = str(decoded_message)
            decoded_message2 = decoded_message1.replace("[", "")
            decoded_message3 = decoded_message2.replace("]", "")
            decoded_message4 = decoded_message3.replace(", ", "")
            decoded_message5 = decoded_message4.replace("'", "")
            if tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Succesfully Generated", message="Your code is succesfully "
                                                                                  "generated\n"
                                                                                  "with"+str(errors)+"errors.\n"
                                                                                  "This is your code:\n" +
                                                                                  decoded_message5 +
                                                                                  "Copy it on the clipboard?"):
                root.clipboard_clear()
                root.clipboard_append(decoded_message5)
            else:
                pass
        elif v == "utf-8 hex":
            for i in decoded_message:
                for char, code in utf8hex:
                    if char == i:
                        encoded_message.append(code)
                    else:
                        errors += 1
                        pass
        elif v == "Ascii":
            for i in decoded_message:
                for char, code in Ascii:
                    if char == i:
                        encoded_message.append(code)
                    else:
                        errors += 1
                        pass
        elif v == "binary":
            for i in decoded_message:
                for char, code in binary:
                    if char == i:
                        encoded_message.append(code)
                    else:
                        errors += 1
                        pass
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title="FATAL ERROR", message="Please, select an encode type.")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR 404", message="ERROR 404: message not found!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a definition problem there: your callback defintion is never reached,as Tkinter's `mainloop` is called before. What happens when the Button is pressed, it tries to call the button object itself, not the `encode` function defined bellow.

To get it working as is, simply move your `root.mainloop()` to the last line of the script.

Besides that, you are calling the Button and your callback function with the same name. That would work (and may have worked in other versions of the program), if you start Tkinter's loop after defining the callback function, and if you won't need access to the Button itself afterwards. You should use different names.

But better than different names, there is an organisation problem of trying to put your interface definition code in the program root level, instead of inside a function.

Comment: If you move _only_ `root.mainloop()`, you'd get `NameError` since the function you are trying to call is not defined at that point. That's why I've said "you should move your function definition above" which solves both NameError and mainloop.

Comment: It won't cause a "naemerror" because in that code is wrapped in a "lambda" expression: it will be evaluated only at "click time".

Comment: Oh shoot. Missed that completely. You are right, sorry. :)

Comment: Another question: i do what you say to me but when i select an encoding type and i write a message, it say to me to choose an encoding type, why?

Comment: I can't understand this question. how do you select an encoding type, and how does it "ask you" to choose an encoding type?

Comment: @jsbueno after i select an encoding type and i write a message, when i click on the "encode" button, it say me to choose an enode type. Pratically it execute the line 21 (counting from the declaration of the encode() function)